# Git: try to diff with old commit

Tags: git

I try to diff file with a commit way old in log. So using commit number would be more straightforward than counting from HEAD. I tried some of the commands I found but not working very well and there is something I don't understand.

For example, this works.

```
$ git diff 72cb273a5c1b5132abb50e244656bf03b4a62191
```

which means it understands the hash number.

But then why this doesn't? Isn't this so intuitive?

```
$ git diff validate.c 72cb273a5c1b5132abb50e244656bf03b4a62191
fatal: ambiguous argument '72cb273a5c1b5132abb50e244656bf03b4a62191': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions
```

And how to make it work? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The revision comes first. It is trying to process `72cb273a5c1b5132abb50e244656bf03b4a62191` as a filename and isn't finding it.

```
git diff 72cb273a5c1b5132abb50e244656bf03b4a62191 validate.c
```